# Required Flash Player for Flash Catalyst

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flashcatalyst

I know that Flash Catalyst is still in Beta, but I'm trying to look ahead. A lot of our users are on intranets whose IT staff require a lot of lead time to upgrade the Flash Player on user's computers. Right now most users are on Flash Player 9.

So my question is, will SWF files created with Flash Catalyst require Flash Player 10?

Comment: The [catalyst] tag is being used for the Perl Catalyst framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flex 4 Gumbo stuff, which catalyst is based on, currently requires Flash 9.  But catalyst is probably a year away from shipping.  There's a good chance things could change.  Especially if Catalyst is built up to use the new font rendering system in Flash 10.

Also, that means applications built using catalyst are probably 18 months or so away.

Comment: Adobe has stated that Flex 4 will require Flash Player 10. Catalyst will have the same requirement.